# iOS VK SDK - не возвращает в приложение после авторизации в приложении ВК

Tags: swift

У меня в приложении есть ВК шаринг. После того, как пользователь нажимает на кнопку, вызывающую шаринг, его перебрасывает в ВК приложение, в котором он подтверждает разрешения. Проблема в том, что после подтверждения пользователя не возвращает в приложение, где был нажат шаринг. Вместо этого пользователь остается в ВК приложении и перед ним отображается лента постов.

в info.plist у меня добавлено

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>vkauthorize</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>vk0000000</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>vk0000000</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

в appDelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

    VKSdk.processOpenURL(url, fromApplication: sourceApplication)

    return true
}
```

в контролере откуда вызывается шаринг

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    VKSdk.initializeWithDelegate(self, andAppId: "5087664")

    if VKSdk.wakeUpSession() {


    }
    }

func vkSdkNeedCaptchaEnter(captchaError: VKError!) {

}

func vkSdkTokenHasExpired(expiredToken: VKAccessToken!) {

}

func vkSdkUserDeniedAccess(authorizationError: VKError!) {

}

func vkSdkShouldPresentViewController(controller: UIViewController!) {

}

func vkSdkReceivedNewToken(newToken: VKAccessToken!) {

}

@IBAction func shareToVK(sender: AnyObject) {

    var imgArray = [AnyObject]()

    let share = VKShareDialogController()
    share.text = "Клевое приложение про танки!"
    let img = VKUploadImage(image:imgToShare, andParams: nil)
    imgArray.append(img)
    let link = NSURL(string: "www.ya.ru")
    share.shareLink = VKShareLink(title: "Preved", link: link)
    share.uploadImages = imgArray

    share.completionHandler = { (result : VKShareDialogControllerResult) -> Void in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    self.presentViewController(share, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

В чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то тут все описано -> http://vk.com/dev/ios_sdk

Comment: @cmashinho да, я все делал по шагам, которые описаны по ссылке

Comment: Посмотрите тут: https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-ios-sdk/issues/286

Answer (score 1):

Sample:

```
-(void)viewDidload{
     VKSdk *sdkInstance = [VKSdk initializeWithAppId:@"your_vk_id_app"];
    [sdkInstance registerDelegate:self];
    [sdkInstance setUiDelegate:self];
}

-(void)postToVK{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    //delay 0,3 sec
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ });

    if (![self.presentedViewController isBeingDismissed])
    {
       [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }
    VKShareDialogController * shareDialog = [VKShareDialogController new]; //1
    shareDialog.text = textBody; //2
    shareDialog.requestedScope = [[VKSdk accessToken] permissions]; // передаём права явно
    //shareDialog.vkImages     = @[@"-10889156_348122347",@"7840938_319411365",@"-60479154_333497085"];
    shareDialog.shareLink = [[VKShareLink alloc] initWithTitle:[_adsObject adstopic] link:[NSURL URLWithString:[_adsObject adslink]]]; //4
    [shareDialog setCompletionHandler: ^(VKShareDialogController *dialog, VKShareDialogControllerResult result)
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
    //5
    [self presentViewController:shareDialog animated:YES completion:nil]; //6
}

- (NSArray *)activityViewController:(NSArray *)activityViewController itemsForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType {

if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail]) {
    return @[emailBody];
}

if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMessage]) {
    return @[textBody];
}
// Automatically copy the text for them
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setString:textBody];
//[self showPopupWithTitle:nil mesage:NSLocalizedString(@"COPYPAST", nil) dismissAfter:1.0];

BOOL isInstalledfb = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://"]];

if (isInstalledfb) {

    //installed

    if([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook] ||
       [activityType isEqualToString:@"com.facebook.Facebook.ShareExtension"] ||
       [activityType.lowercaseString rangeOfString:@"facebook"].length)
        // Because who knows when they are going to change the activityType string?
    {

        //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        [self performSelector:@selector(postToFacebook) withObject:self afterDelay:1];

        return nil;
    }

}

BOOL isInstalledtw = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://"]];

if (isInstalledtw) {

    //installed
    if([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter] )
        // Because who knows when they are going to change the activityType string?
    {
        [self showPopupWithTitle:nil mesage:NSLocalizedString(@"COPYPAST", nil) dismissAfter:1.0];
       // [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        //[self performSelector:@selector(postToTwitter) withObject:self afterDelay:1];
         return nil;
    }

} else {
    // not instaled
}

BOOL isInstalledvk = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"vk://"]];

if (isInstalledvk) {
   //installed

    SCOPE = @[VK_PER_FRIENDS, VK_PER_WALL, VK_PER_AUDIO, VK_PER_PHOTOS, VK_PER_NOHTTPS, VK_PER_EMAIL, VK_PER_MESSAGES];

    [VKSdk wakeUpSession:SCOPE completeBlock:^(VKAuthorizationState state, NSError *error) {
       // NSLog(@"state vk = %lu",(unsigned long)state);
        if (state == VKAuthorizationAuthorized) {
            // Authorized and ready to go
            // NSLog(@" vk ready auth");

                [self performSelector:@selector(postToVK) withObject:self afterDelay:0.2];
        }
        if (state == VKAuthorizationInitialized){
            // need Authorized
            // NSLog(@" vk need auth");
            [VKSdk authorize:SCOPE];

        }
        if(error) {
            // Some error happend, but you may try later
             NSLog(@"vk some error");
        }
    }];

    return nil;

} else {
    // vk app not instaled
   return @[textBody, myWebsite];
}

return nil;

}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы вам признателен за ваши комментарии по теме вопроса.